# Extract Unique Substring from Range of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have cell values with names that are fairly close to each other. I would like to extract a common sub-string.

Here is an example.

```
1100_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_S_run1 
1100_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_S_run2
1100_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_S_run3 
1100_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_S_run4 
1101_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run5 
1101_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run6 
1102_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run7 
1102_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run8 
1102_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run9 
1102_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_U_run10
```

The output should be `_250_Jump_12HR_100MD_`

How can I extract a common sub-string in Excel?

I checked similar questions but could not find the answer.

Comment: Just to be certain, I assume you don't know ahead of time what the substring is? How small or large is an acceptable substring? in your sample data, would `100MD` be long enough? Will the matching substring always start in the same position (6th character in your sample data)? Also, can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344601/excel-determine-if-two-cells-match-based-on-consecutive-matching-characters/53346098#53346098) to be of interest towards reaching a solution

Comment: No. I don't know the substring ahead of time. Also, the length of it is not fixed. It definitely not too long. The substring does not always start at the same position. I have tried to play around with UNIQUE, MID, but with no success at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the UDF in the link I posted in comments:

```
Option Explicit


Public Function CSTMatch3(Target1 As Range, Target2 As Range) As String

CSTMatch3 = ""

Dim myString As String, String1 As String, String2 As String, i As Long, j As Long, noChar As Long

noChar = 0

'The goal here is to assign the larger String to the variable String1
If Target1 = Target2 Then
    CSTMatch3 = Target1
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(Target1) >= Len(Target2) Then
    String1 = Target1
    String2 = Target2
Else
    String1 = Target2
    String2 = Target1
End If

For j = 1 To Len(String2)
    For i = 1 To Len(String1) - j
        If InStr(String2, Mid(String1, i, j)) Then
            myString = Mid(String1, i, j)
            noChar = noChar + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next j

CSTMatch3 = myString

End Function
```

Then, assuming you strings are in column `A`, Use the UDF in `B1` like this:

```
=CSTMatch3(A1,A2)
```

Then in `B2`:

```
=CSTMatch3(A2,B1)
```

And populate down.

Cells in column `B` in any given row now show the common string for all cells in `A` up to that row.

[image]