# Extracting Partial Matching Text from two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm looking for a solution for comparing two cells with text, and extracting only the part of the two cells that match.   for example:

Cell A1:  "Yesterday I ate an apple"
Cell A2:  "today I ate an orange"

how can I extract " I ate an " into another cell?

Does someone have a user defined function I can plug into VBA, or is there a fancy way to use existing functions to do this?

Comment: Will the string have to be in that exact order?  Given `Yesterday I ate an apple` and if `A2` has `ate apple`, will you expect `ate` and `apple` to be counted?

Comment: Good question...  Ideally no, but I see how that makes this difficult.   The example I gave in the question was greatly simplified.  in reality, the data i am working with is much more unique, and it is unlikely that there will be an instance like that.   you can also assume that there will indeed be a matching substring 3-10 words long

Comment: And do you want whole words only? because the longest match between `Yesterday I ate an apple` and `today I ate an orange` is `day I ate an `

Comment: yes, whole words only would be ideal,  again probably making this more difficult.  Appreciate the questions, thank you.

Comment: You may find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1381461/extract-unique-substring-from-range-of-excel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344601/excel-determine-if-two-cells-match-based-on-consecutive-matching-characters/53346098#53346098) to give you a starting point for what you want

Comment: Suppose both share words like "a", "an",  "and", "or", "the", etc.  The odds are good that any two phrases will have some amount of matching words.  This is much more complex that it appears on the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** Now includes an ignored word list.

WordSequence : After rudimentary word parsing looks for the longest matching word sequence based on the character count of those words. Returns the sequence as it occurs in the first argument.

Usage: WordSequence (String1, String2 [, caseInsensitive As Boolean])

Example 1 - The OP sample data with `IgnoredWords = "a an"` as coded below.
`=WordSequence("Yesterday I ate an apple", "today I ate an orange")`
Result: `I ate`

Example 2 - Same sample data with edit `IgnoredWords = ""` to code (no ignored words).
`=WordSequence("Yesterday I ate an apple", "today I ate an orange")`
Result: `I ate an`

Example 3 - Results can vary based on which String is assigned to the String1 parameter.
. [image: WordSequence formula used in a spreadsheet]
B1:C2 show the effect of string input order on the returned value.
B3:C4 Demonstrate `caseInsensitive := TRUE` (and input order return value).

Note: In example 3 `IgnoredWords = "a an"` as coded below. In this case, the same match will occur even if `a` or `an` is missing from one cell or the other. Further, the return result will include `a` or `an` when it occurs in String1 and is inclusive to the matching sequence. The example 1 result also illustrates `IgnoredWords` do not appear at the beginning or at the end of the matching word sequence. This is because they do not match anything since they were ignored. The same is true for any specified punctuation characters.

```
' WordSequence (String1, String2 [, caseInsensitive As Boolean])
'
'    Compares two String arguments for the longest common sequence
'    of words. Longest is defined by the number of characters in each
'    matched word in the sequence.
'
'    Make the comparison case insensitive with an optional third
'    argument set to True.
'
'    Return the sequence of words from String1 along with inclusive
'       text (white space, ignored words and specified punctuation).
'
' Authored by Ted Dillard
'
' Spaces, Tabs and the WordBoundary characters delimit the words
'    in the comparison; only whole word matches are returned.
'
' Punctuation Indifference:  Two mechanisms regulate matching based on
'    specified punctuation characters. The matched sequence in String1
'    is returned with any inclusive punctuation. Spaces, tabs and the
'    defined punctuations are not counted when comparing match lengths.
'    Any punctuation not specified in one of these two constants is
'    treated as a character of the word (like the apostrophe in "I'll")
'
' Ignored Words: A list of words to ignore in matching. These words'
'    lengths are not counted towards the longest match. Theses words
'    will only be returned if they are between two matched words
'    in String1, in which case they will be returned even if not in
'    String2, because they were ignored.
'
Option Explicit
'
' IgnoredWords is a String of space separated words to ignore. Punctuation
'    not listed in WordBoundary or IgnoredPunctuation can be in the words.
Private Const IgnoredWords = "a an"  ' "" empty string ok
'
' (Two consecutive double quotes inside a quoted string puts one
'    double quote into the string value.)
'
' WordBoundary characters are word delimiters and ignored in matching.
Private Const wordBoundary = "(){}[]:;<>,.?!"""
'
' IgnoredPunctuation are deleted before parsing words (ignored in matching).
'    Therefore "'.-" means "we're"="were" and "123.456.7890"="123-456-7890"
Private Const IgnoredPunctuation = "-"
'
' WhiteSpace characters are used as word boundaries along with spaces.
Private Const WhiteSpace = vbTab & vbNewLine & vbLf & vbCr & vbCrLf
'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
' END of User Configurable Settings - the rest is code
'
Private Enum WordList
    matchOnWords ' list first =0 also missing Optional Long parameter value
    NonDeletion
    AllPartials
End Enum
Private Type LongestMatch
    start As Long
    items As Long
End Type

Public Function WordSequence(ByVal sentence As String, ByVal sentence2 _
        As String, Optional caseInsensitive As Boolean) As String
    Dim matchOnWords() As String
    Dim matchInfo As LongestMatch

    'Optional Booleans are False by default. If Case_Insensitive is True the
    'search will not be case sensitive. The default search is case sensitive.
    'To make default case insensitive, change parameter name to caseSensitve
    'and edit If condition to "Not caseSensitive"
    WordSequence = sentence
    If caseInsensitive Then
        sentence = LCase(sentence)
        sentence2 = LCase(sentence2)
    End If

    matchOnWords = getWords(sentence)
    matchInfo = getLongestMatch(matchOnWords, getWords(sentence2))
    If matchInfo.start = -1 Or matchInfo.items = 0 Then
        WordSequence = ""
    Else
        WordSequence = getMatchedString(sentence, WordSequence, matchOnWords, _
                matchInfo.start, matchInfo.items)
    End If
End Function

Private Function getMatchedString(ByVal sentence As String, _
        ByVal original As String, ByRef matchOnWords() As String, _
        ByVal start As Long, ByVal items As Long) As String
    Dim allPartialWords() As String
    Dim allWords() As String
    Dim begun As Boolean, ignoredWord As Boolean, wordBoundary As Boolean
    Dim w As Long, i  As Long, j As Long

    ' word list where all specified punctuations are used as word boundaries,
    ' [1] to deal with punctuation in the actual word but not the match words
    allPartialWords = getWords(sentence, AllPartials)
    allWords = getWords(sentence, NonDeletion) 'deals with ignored words
    begun = False
    ignoredWord = False
    wordBoundary = True
    i = 0: j = 0
    For w = 0 To UBound(allPartialWords)
        ' make the beginning of the sentence be the beginning location of the
        '    first occurrence in the sentence where the current iterative word
        '    list element (partial word) is located removing preceding spaces,
        '    tabs and punctuation characters defined in punctuation constants.
        sentence = Mid(sentence, InStr(sentence, allPartialWords(w)))
        If Not begun And i = start Then 'Beginning of words match
            begun = True
            ' delete any characters at the beginning of the original sentence
            '    that have already been removed from the sentence variable
            original = Mid(original, Len(original) - Len(sentence) + 1)
        End If
        ' remove the current partial word from the beginning of the sentence
        sentence = Mid(sentence, Len(allPartialWords(w)) + 1)

        If wordBoundary Then
            ' is entirety of all_word in ignored word list
            If InStr(" " & IgnoredWords & " ", " " & allWords(j) & " ") Then
                ignoredWord = True
            End If
        End If
        ' also remove from the beginning of all_word & match_word, along with
        ' [1] preceding ignored characters inclusive to this matchOnWord.
        allWords(j) = Mid(allWords(j), InStr(allWords(j), _
                allPartialWords(w)) + Len(allPartialWords(w)))
         ' ignored words are not part of match_on_words' list
        If Not ignoredWord Then
            matchOnWords(i) = Mid(matchOnWords(i), InStr(matchOnWords(i), _
                    allPartialWords(w)) + Len(allPartialWords(w)))
        End If
        If allWords(j) = "" Then ' all_word is consumed
            wordBoundary = True  ' no longer in a word,
            ignoredWord = False  ' so can no longer be in an ignored word
            j = j + 1
        Else ' part of the word is consumed, next time through dont test the
            wordBoundary = False ' remaing part against ignored word list
        End If

        If matchOnWords(i) = "" Then ' match_on_word is consumed
            i = i + 1 ' advance match_on_word iterator to next matched word
            If begun Then
                items = items - 1 'consumed word, decrement matched items count
                If items = 0 Then ' consumed all matched words.
                    ' original already starts at beginning of match.
                    ' sentence had all matched partial words removed.
                    ' remove rest of sentence characters from return value.
                    getMatchedString = Mid(original, 1, _
                            Len(original) - Len(sentence))
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next w
    getMatchedString = ""
End Function

Private Function getLongestMatch(ByRef words1() As String, _
        ByRef words2() As String) As LongestMatch
    Dim largestCharCnt As Long

    largestCharCnt = 0
    getLongestMatch.start = -1
    getLongestMatch.items = 0
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i As Long, l As Long
    For i1 = 0 To UBound(words1)
        For i2 = 0 To UBound(words2)
            If words1(i1) = words2(i2) Then
                l = Len(words1(i1))
                i = 1
                Do While i1 + i <= UBound(words1)
                    If i2 + i > UBound(words2) Then Exit Do
                    If words1(i1 + i) <> words2(i2 + i) Then Exit Do
                    l = l + Len(words1(i1 + i))
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
                If l > largestCharCnt Then
                    largestCharCnt = l
                    getLongestMatch.start = i1
                    getLongestMatch.items = i
                End If
            End If
        Next i2
    Next i1
End Function

Private Function getWords(ByVal sentence As String, _
        Optional listType As WordList) As String()

    sentence = replaceChars(sentence, WhiteSpace, " ")
    sentence = replaceChars(sentence, wordBoundary, " ")

    If listType = matchOnWords Or listType = NonDeletion Then
        sentence = replaceChars(sentence, IgnoredPunctuation, "")
    Else ' listType = AllPartials
        sentence = replaceChars(sentence, IgnoredPunctuation, " ")
    End If
    If listType = matchOnWords Then
        ' start & end as well for space delimiter-brackets' match
        sentence = " " & sentence & " "
        Dim w As Variant
        ' only match whole word using space delimiter-brackets' match
        For Each w In Split(IgnoredWords)
            sentence = Replace(sentence, " " & w & " ", " ")
        Next w
    End If
    Do While InStr(sentence, "  ") <> 0
        sentence = Replace(sentence, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    sentence = Trim(sentence)
    getWords = Split(sentence)
End Function

Private Function replaceChars(ByVal source As String, ByVal chars As String, _
            ByVal replacement As String) As String
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To Len(chars)
        source = Replace(source, Mid(chars, c, 1), replacement)
    Next c
    replaceChars = source
End Function
```

Comment: Could you add some output,, how & what it finds and delivers !!

Comment: Yes, definitely. I will update my answer to include a usage example. I have also added the ability to ignore words when matching and will include this new version in my edit.

Comment: Ted,  this is fantastic.   Works like a dream for my needs.   thank you for going above and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write Search String in **M25.**
2. Find Length of Search String in **N25.**

   `=LEN($M$25)`
3. To find position of Search String use this in **O25** & fill down.

   `=SEARCH($M$25,L25,1)`
4. Finally write this to extract the Search String in **P25** & fill it down.

   `=MID(L25,O25,$N$25)`

**N.B.**

1. Above shown method is easiest, and Extracts the Search String from any Length of Text.
2. This method can be used to extract any String as I've shown with **fast car** also.
3. Using **SEARCH** to find position, ultimately empowers the Formula to handle Case Sensitive strings also.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I would like to suggest two different Formula, will extract "**I ate an**" from text string in a cell.

- Formula for *A2, A3 & A4*,  where **"I ate an",  preceded by one word only.**

  ```
  =TRIM(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),4))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),2))+2))
  ```
- Formula for *A7*, where **"I ate an", preceded by two words.**

  ```
  =TRIM(MID(A7,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A7," ",CHAR(1),1))+6,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A7," ",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A7," ",CHAR(1),1))+2))
  ```

**How it works:**

`FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),4))`

returns `19`, which is `Start Position` of the Search string,  **I ate an**.

```
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(C7," ",CHAR(1),4))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(C7," ",CHAR(1),2))+1
```

returns `8` the length of  **I ate an** (including spaces).

```
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ,CHAR(1),2))+2
```

returns `14` & gets **I ate an apple**.

```
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(C7," ",CHAR(1),4))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(C7," ",CHAR(1),2))+2
```

returns `9` which subtracts `14-9 = 5`, removes **I ate an** from **Apple,**

Makes the Formula:

```
=MID(C7,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(C7," ",CHAR(1),1))+1,8)
```

returns, **I ate an** the expected answer.

**Edited:**

*This improvised Formula is extracting text string, **I ate an** from **all possible combinations shown below.***

[image]

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),MAX(99,FIND(" I",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))-50),299))
```

**How it works:**

- Formula inserts large number of spaces between words in text string, finds and extracts the expected substring, and TRIM function cleans extra spaces.

`SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99))`

Replaces each single space with 99 spaces.

**Note,** `99` is just an arbitrary number that represents the longest word you need to extract.

```
    FIND(" I",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))-50
```

- FIND returns the position of the `" I"`.
- Subtracting `50` effectively sets the position  in the middle of the spaces preceding the substring of interest.

**Note,** In this Formula the calculated position is `366`.

- With a starting positing, `MID` is used to extract `99` characters of text, starting at `366` from the text in `
- `A1`, again filled with space.
- `MAX` handles the problem of the substring appearing first in the text, here position is negative, and `MAX` resets it to `1`.

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: This might miss the intent of the question.  The idea isn't to extract a known phrase from a certain position.  It's to find whether there is any phrase common to both, potentially in different locations in each, and extract that.  The first step is comparing the two strings to identify what they have in common.

Comment: @fixer1234,, yeah you are write,, and my solution is exactly working for that Match cells and Extract the common one !

Comment: @fixer1234,, this is the OP's twist,, " **I'm looking for a solution for comparing two cells with text, and extracting only the part of the two cells that match. for example:**

**how can I extract " I ate an " into another cell?**

Comment: A1: `I ate an orange today.`  A2: `Sometime last week I ate an orange apple.`  How would your solution figure out what the two have in common and extract it?  That's the task.  You don't know in advance what the commonality is or where it occurs.

Comment: @fixer1234,, check my second Formula which find **I ate an** from text where the position is different. And I've created Formula on given examples

Comment: @fixer1234, it's true that single formula can't cater in every situation.

Comment: @fixer1234,, i'm near to find a common solution ☺

Comment: @fixer1234, check the edited part this formula is solving almost everything.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it's only good when the the common phrase is "I ate an".  What happens if A1: `fast cars go quickly`  A2: `I love fast cars` (or any random phrases)?  The task is first to identify any word sequence two string have in common.

Comment: Most difficult part of the question is to determine common part of the substrings and your post takes that as given. This is not a solution of the problem, not even an important step which would worth posting it as an answer.

Comment: The question is really way out of scope.  This would take a mini-application (like Ted D.'s answer, assuming it works).  How often have you seen "Super User is not a free coding site" commented on questions?  :-)

Comment: not looking for free coding service here...   I simply wanted to see if there is in fact a simple way of doing this.   If the answer is "no," I completely understand.  I am grateful for the effort that was put into my question.

Comment: @Jamiho, did you every try my solutions? I've solved it!

Comment: @fixer1234,, you know better such questions have situational answer, Coz of LENGTH of text only, & what matters is whether it works or not,, Yes currently it's working,,, I've included many similar text including yours too,, **Sometimes last week I ate an orange apple** and being seasoned user you know better ANY FORMULA can't click with EVERYTHING,, especially Formula extracts Text, since Length is a big issue !!

Comment: @Rajesh S,  thank you for your effort.   For my needs,  the common substring is not known, and differs across my data, so your solution will not work.

Comment: @Jamiho,, if the common text is not known then better edit the question and mention, that COMMON TEXT is unknown, and in this case the examples you have given is irrelevant also. If you may need to search any text then check my second answer, it's searching any text !!