# Excel Fuzzy Lookup Company Names in the Same list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of company names - I've done a lot of cleaning up to get to this list. Some of the company names are slightly different like `2J Antennas, s.r.o.` and `2J Antennas USA, Corporation` or [image] all the companies below are the same.

Is there a way to use fuzzymatch on the same list? I've tried copying the data to create 2 lists but it just returns the 1.0 matches for everything.

Am i missing something there is there not really a way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what would the end goal look like?

Comment: End goal would just be a list of "unique" values - however, when I say unique, I mean "fuzzy unique" if that makes any sense. ie those two examples I gave above would just be 2 names 1. 2J Antennas, s.r.o and Bosch[Robert Bosch LLC]

Comment: You need to explain in more details, things can be clear in your mind, but we can't read it. What is the criteria to determine a fuzzy match? If "ABC national manufacturing group" matches "ABC local retail corp.", does "Bosch[Robert Bosch LLC]" match "Boston manufacturing Inc." (both have the same first three characters...)

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/1381461/extract-unique-substring-from-range-of-excel/1381470#1381470)

Comment: You can use fuzzy matching in Power Query, but you will still need to configure it correctly. I recommend you begin by creating a list of master descriptions to which you want to match, then match your "dirty" company names against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a cell in your list, then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

This will open the Power Query Editor:

[image]

Change the type of the column to Text by clicking the data type icon in the top left of the column header.

Then, go to Home>Advanced Editor> and modify the query by adding a FuzzyGroup transformation:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data", type text}}),
    #"FuzzyGroup" = Table.FuzzyGroup(#"Changed Type","Data",{{"Count",each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}},[Threshold=0.2])
in
    #"FuzzyGroup"
```

Note that you must:

1. Add a comma to the end of the "Changed Type" line
2. Add the "FuzzyGroup" line (call it whatever you want)
3. Change the "in" part to say "FuzzyGroup" (this must match whatever name you chose in step 2
4. Add optional parameters inside the square brackets to configure your fuzzy group. The default Threshold is, I believe, 0.8. That doesn't really help with your example data, so I've changed it to 0.2. Experiment with different values of Threshold and be careful that you don't create false positives.

More details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fuzzygroup).

[image]